# How to run nuxt plugins before global middleware?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In my web app with nux3,

- I use firebase for authentication. So I used a nuxt plugin to init a firebase app.
- Then I wanna use a global nuxt middleware to check if the user is loggedIn. If not redirect to other pages.I mean add nevigation guard.

But what I can see or understand that nuxt middleware run before the plugin init the firebase app. So what is the best way to deal this situations?

- Is there any way to run middleware after plugins?
- Or there is any better and cleaner approch for this case?

Comment: Try running as a router middleware (to configure in the nuxt config file)?

Comment: Did it helped anyhow?

Comment: I found a [PR](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/pull/4645) that nuxt 3 already run middleware after plugin. But somehow my firebase init app don't load in firebase middleware. Your commnet somehow help me to think and try a another way. But I did not tried it yet.

Comment: I have same problem and i don't know how to to solve this, did you solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this [Pull Request](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/pull/4645) description said

> This PR changes middleware behaviour to defer processing middleware until after plugins are initialised. This means that middleware will have access to plugin injections, and that plugins have the chance to add middleware themselves.

So that means, In Nuxt 3 by default middleware will have access to plugin injections.

Now for my above question, currently what I am doing is, running my full firebase auth in client side. To run firebase auth only in client side,I have done this,

- Add firebase plugin in client side only by renaming it like `firebase.client.ts`
- Run middleware only when `process.client` is true
- This [PR](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/2404) might help you more, for client side firebase auth.

**But I still don't know how to run firebase plugin in server side properly. So add another question about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73295610/nuxt-3-firebase-plugins-erros-component-auth-has-not-been-registered-yet)**