# Nuxt 3 firebase plugins erros Component auth has not been registered yet

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In my project under plugins dir I have a single plugins called `firebase.ts` and it's look like this

```js
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from "#app";
import { firebaseConfig } from "@/firebaseConfig";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  // Initialize Firebase
  const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const firebaseAuthInstance = getAuth(firebaseApp);
})
```

Whenever I run my project it's give this kind of error. But if I make the plugin client only i mean `firebase.client.ts` then it work just fine. But I want to get this pluin both in client and server side. How to achive that?

```
[h3] [unhandled] H3Error: Component auth has not been registered yet
    at createError (file:///home/riyad/Desktop/nuxt-test/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:238:15)
    at Server.nodeHandler (file:///home/riyad/Desktop/nuxt-test/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:428:21) {
  statusCode: 500,
  fatal: false,
  unhandled: true,
  statusMessage: 'Internal Server Error'
}
[nuxt] [request error] Component auth has not been registered yet
  at createError (./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:238:15)  
  at Server.nodeHandler (./node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:428:21)
```

Comment: Did you gave a try to those: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions?discussions_q=has+not+been+registered+yet ?

Comment: Yes, I have read those discussions. All of them use `firebase.client.ts` type solution, I mean render plugin only in client side.

Comment: The module is maybe just not supporting SSR due to it's implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase libraries use browser cache to store data on client side, so you cannot load some of their libraries on server side. Auth library is used and works only on client site, same as all lib's with no `/lite` end. To be able to use library Firestore on server, import all functions from `'firebase/firestore/lite'` file path.

Example of plugin:

```js
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app'
import { initializeApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app'
import { connectFirestoreEmulator as connectFirestoreEmulatorServer, getFirestore as getFirestoreServer } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'

import { connectAuthEmulator, getAuth } from "firebase/auth"
import { connectDatabaseEmulator, getDatabase } from "firebase/database"
import { connectFirestoreEmulator, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
import { connectFunctionsEmulator, getFunctions } from "firebase/functions"
import { connectStorageEmulator, getStorage } from "firebase/storage"

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {

  const firebaseConfig = { ...useRuntimeConfig().public.firebaseConfig }

  if (!getApps().length) initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

  // Code bellow allows to work with local emulators you can delete it if you work without emulators
  if(!process.dev) return

  const firestoreHost = getFirestoreServer().toJSON()['settings'].host

  if(firestoreHost !== 'localhost:8080') {
    connectFirestoreEmulatorServer(getFirestoreServer(), 'localhost', 8080)
  }

  if (process.client) {
    connectAuthEmulator(getAuth(), "http://localhost:9099")
    connectFirestoreEmulator(getFirestore(), "localhost", 8080)
    connectDatabaseEmulator(getDatabase(), "localhost", 9000)
    connectStorageEmulator(getStorage(), "localhost", 9199)
    connectFunctionsEmulator(getFunctions(), "localhost", 5001)
  }
  
})
```

Usage:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="signIn">Sign In</button>
    <p>{{ data.test.title }}</p>
    <p>User email: {{userEmail}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { getAuth, OAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from 'firebase/auth';
import { doc, getDoc, getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

const data = reactive({ test: null })
const userEmail = ref('')

const result = await getDoc(doc(getFirestore(), 'test/test'))
if (result.exists()) data.test = result.data()

// Here example how you can run code only on client.
// There is `process.server` too.
if (process.client) {
  const userCredentials = await signInWithPopup(getAuth(), new OAuthProvider('google.com'))
  if (userCredentials.user) userEmail.value = userCredentials.user.email
}

async function signIn() {
  const userCredentials = await signInWithPopup(getAuth(), new OAuthProvider('google.com'))
  if (userCredentials.user) userEmail.value = userCredentials.user.email
}
</script>
```

Code directly in setup will run on server and client. Function `signIn` and `if (process.client)` will run only on client same as life cycle hooks like `onMounted()`

Comment: Your answer just saved a life.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I was able to solve the issue. Here is the code on the directory /plugins/plugins.ts:

```
import { getAuth } from "@firebase/auth";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { firebaseConfig } from "./firebase/firebaseConfig";

const authInstance = () => {
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    return auth
};

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    return {
        provide: {
            authInstance,
        },
    };
});
```

It appears that the initializeApp Function was not called correctly. But if you call the initializeApp and getAuth on a new function it returns The Auth Object correctly.

Comment: Think its a bit more subtle than that. Here you are "providing" a function that will initialise the app and return the auth instance when it is called (as opposed to when the nuxt app loads). As a result, you're probably only calling $authInstance() from client side code so it works.